# Ambiguous redirect when running configure with hush

Tags: linux, shell, busybox

I am running a simple linux system with busybox and hush as the shell.
When I try to run the standard "./configure" for compiling programs, I always get the following error:

```
/Programs/blazeos/build/bison-3.4.1 # ./configure
hush: ambiguous redirect
hush: syntax error at 'fi'
```

If I run it with "ash ./configure" it runs without any problems, so it seems to be related to the hush shell. Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can debug it? I have tried it with several different source packages, such as "flex", "bison", "m4" etc. and I always get the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately, hush doesn't *claim* to be a POSIX-compliant shell (and thus able to be used to run scripts written to run on any standards-compliant shell), or even a fully Bourne-compatible shell. Any chance you could modify your busybox build flags to enable its ash variant?

Comment: "There is [no support in hush](https://barebox.org/doc/latest/user/hush.html) for input/output redirection or pipes. " haha wow, yeah don't use that as `/bin/sh`on a general purpose system

Comment: @thatotherguy, ...[current hush](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/shell/hush.c?h=1_18_stable&id=30f0ea6cab956ed59ecc5de82459187763a2b868) *does* support pipes and some limited I/O redirection, just not as much as is needed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually, I was using ash first, but I switched to hush because ash do not support curly braces. Seems both shells included with busybox are flawed :( Why would anyone build a shell and not even check if it supports something so basic as running "configure" for compiling programs. Weird in my opinion.

Comment: "do not support curly braces"? Huh? ash certainly does support `${foo}`, and `{ someCommand; someOtherCommand; }`. It doesn't support [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), but that's not POSIX-standardized functionality, so scripts that assume it works are buggy if they're supposed to run on POSIX-baseline shells. I certainly wouldn't expect `configure` to make any assumptions of that sort.

Comment: Do you have any trouble running your configure script with busybox's ash, in practice?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about brace expansion. It's used in a lot of existing scripts. No, like I said, running "ash Configure" works. However, hush has a "bash compatible" setting in Busybox, as well as being more feature rich. I find it odd that they did not add the features needed to run a standard configure script, which is probably the most commonly run scripts in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

This happens in `as_fn_error`:

```
as_fn_error ()
{
  as_status=$1; test $as_status -eq 0 && as_status=1
  if test "$4"; then
    as_lineno=${as_lineno-"$3"} as_lineno_stack=as_lineno_stack=$as_lineno_stack
    $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: error: $2" >&$4
  fi
  $as_echo "$as_me: error: $2" >&2
  as_fn_exit $as_status
} # as_fn_error
```

This happens because `>&$4` (getting the file descriptor number to redirect to by evaluating `$4`) is not supported in hush. Arguably, this violates the letter of [the POSIX sh standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_06); bolding for emphasis is mine:

> The redirection operator: `[n]>&word` shall duplicate one output file descriptor from another, or shall close one. If *word* **evaluates to** one or more digits, the file descriptor denoted by `n`, or standard output if `n` is not specified, shall be made to be a copy of the file descriptor denoted by *word*

As I read the specification, "evaluates to" means that expansions should be run, so using a parameter expansion should be legal in that location. Thus, this is (arguably) a missing feature in `hush` that would be required for standards compliance.

---

If you're interested in trying to work around the issue, in all the cases where this optional parameter is used, it's given a hardcoded value of `5`. Thus, you could simply change `>&$4` to `>&5`, and this specific error would be avoided.